# What's the word to describe when movies try hard to evoke emotion?

Tags: single-word-requests

Some movies overplay/over-do certain elements to make viewers feel emotional - cheesy lines, music and others. I've read a review which used a word to convey this pithily but I can't seem to remember for the life of me!

An example would be: I'm not sure I want to see the new movie. It is XXX.

Edit: added sample sentence.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Could you supply an example sentence where you want to use this word? It will help get you better answers.

Comment: Your example sentence suggests that you are looking for an adjective. *...the movie.... is sentimental* / *cliché* / *sappy* / *soppy* / *a tear-jerker* etc. etc. There's nothing in that sentence to suggest you are looking for an expression or term that suggests the producers' aim is to evoke sentimentalism.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, thank you for the suggestion. Sorry I couldn't express it correctly but Martin Smith has the word I'm looking for.

Comment: You're the OP, and I'm glad you got the answer you wanted but how does *mawkish* fit the criteria you were looking for [*Sappy is what is in the movie. I'm looking for a phrase that would mean **"put in a lot of effort to make it sappy"***](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/297400/whats-the-word-to-describe-when-movies-try-hard-to-evoke-emotion?noredirect=1#comment668007_297403) How does *mawkish* suggest that someone put in a lot of effort to make it "mawkish"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA, you're right. On the face of it, it doesn't. I'd read a movie review a long time ago and *inferred* the meaning of mawkish to mean that. I was looking for something using the wrong description and someone happened to suggest it. Thanks for all your suggestions and help, though!

Comment: Mawkish fits the example sentence in the question anyway. "I'm not sure I want to see the new movie. It is mawkish." would be a totally fine thing to say. And assuming the writers are competent and perfectly capable of writing non mawkish material it probably requires some level of deliberate effort.

Comment: "Overwrought" is specific, but clos(ish). "Mawkish" as Martin Smith mentioned is a good recommendation.

Comment: The movie is a "tear jerker".

Comment: In Dutch we use expression "Painting red roses red" (Rode rozen rood verven). It doesn't answer your question, but I find it too beautiful not to share it here. I don't know if it's used in English.

Comment: @HotLicks you have a habit of not reading previous comments. I already suggested that expression. But you did well to post it as an answer, comments can be deleted at any time.

Comment: Nobody came up with the simple *emotive*: "arousing or able to arouse intense feeling"

Comment: isn't `provocative` the word here? - I mean it usually has negative connotations but the meaning of the word is to evoke a strong reaction(any)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I like the word **[mawkish](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mawkish)**

> sentimental in an exaggerated or false way.

[An Example Usage](http://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/films/reviews/the-best-of-me-film-review-terminally-mawkish-tearjerker-is-hard-to-stomach-9800106.html)

> **The Best Of Me, film review: Terminally mawkish tearjerker is hard to
>   stomach**
>
> Much of the dialogue for this terminally mawkish tearjerker sounds as
>   if it has been taken directly from a Dolly Parton or Whitney Houston
>   song ...

The [etymology of this word is](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mawkish)

> mawkish (adj.) 1660s, "sickly, nauseated," from Middle English mawke
>   "maggot". Sense of "sickly sentimental" is first recorded 1702.

Comment: @hsnk - It's a great word!

Comment: It's a good enough answer that I won't downvote it, but I have to say I've maybe heard this word once or twice in my life - it's so rarely used I won't upvote this either.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - Might be more something that you would see in a UK broadsheet than the US? Some examples 
[Mawkish tabloid fare: how the Amy Winehouse film fails](http://www.newstatesman.com/culture/2015/07/mawkish-tabloid-fare-how-amy-winehouse-film-fails)

[Fathers and Daughters review – mawkish twaddle meets ripe platitudes](http://www.theguardian.com/film/2015/nov/15/fathers-daughters-review-russell-crowe)

[Mr Morgan's Last Love, review: 'mawkish fluff'](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/film/filmreviews/10959233/Mr-Morgans-Last-Love-review-mawkish-fluff.html)

Comment: Ah, it is probably a US/UK thing. Sometimes it's almost enough to want to separate this stack into two - US and non-US.

Comment: Isn't UK English supposed to be the default English? So I suppose, English and 'everything else derived' sounds more appropriate! (:P No offence, just being cheeky)

Comment: @ToddWilcox Sometimes? My decline in posting here is in a direct relationship to my better understanding of the fact that AmE and BrE (will always) have irreconcilable differences. English has way too many dialects for it *not* to be a required tag and any site that attempts to encompass all of them is on tenuous ground at best. I'm sure there's some juicy stuff buried here on SE, where we've tried to reach across the pond and strangle each other.

Comment: As an American of 34 years, I do believe I'd never heard the word "mawkish" before reading this post, and I certainly wouldn't have been able to guess its meaning.

Comment: @ToddWilcox maybe not actually. I've just searched [the Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/newssearch/?query=Mawkish) and [the New York Times](http://query.nytimes.com/search/sitesearch/?action=click&contentCollection&region=TopBar&WT.nav=searchWidget&module=SearchSubmit&pgtype=Homepage#/Mawkish/since1851/allresults/1/allauthors/newest/) and it does get used in those papers too. The NYT used it 4 times in December 2015.

Comment: Is "mawkish" the right word if the emotion they're trying for is fear or anger?

Comment: @bof - No - it definitely is about piling on sentimentality rather than generically applicable to all emotions.

Answer (score 29):

'*Melodramatic*' - most commonly used for movies where emotions interspersed with exaggerated characters, cheesy lines, catchy music and background scores are used to create sensations.

*"It makes me sick when movies with unrealistic and melodramatic endings become huge hits."*

Others words can be -
*saccharine, sugary, maudlin, sloshy, sloppy, rabble-rousing*

Comment: @Théophile My bad :)

Answer (score 16):

Schmaltz was mentioned earlier.

I submit ***sappy***:

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sappy?s=t

Comment: Sappy is what is *in* the movie. I'm looking for a phrase that would mean "put in a lot of effort to make it sappy". Does that makes sense?

Comment: @hsnk: As in "pandering to the gutter" or something?

Comment: *every trick of the trade*?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Yeah, well, I shouldn't always assume the worst.

Comment: @HasanAliKhan That makes sense, but doesn't jive with your example sentence.

Answer (score 16):

Oh, come on! It's a [**tearjerker**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tearjerker)!!

> a story, song, play, film, or broadcast that moves or is intended to
>   move its audience to tears

Comment: In some senses it definitely fits, but I don't know if I've seen it used with the overtly-manipulative or negative connotations that seem to fit some of the alternatives.

Comment: @JeffBowman - I don't think I've ever seen it used in a case where "manipulation" of audience emotions was **not** implied.

Comment: I think this term is used when the correct amount of emotion is used, not when there's too much.

Answer (score 13):

Perhaps the word you are looking for is *[schmaltz](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/schmaltz)*:-

> 1. Informal
>
> a. Excessively sentimental art or music.
>
> b. Maudlin sentimentality.
>
> [American Heritage Dictionary]

Answer (score 13):

How about [corny](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/corny)?  I have used it to talk about movies that are sappy, too sentimental, or try hard to make you feel something.  It's a bit dated but still works.

Answer (score 7):

More technical terms would include "emotionally manipulative" and "sentimental."

More informal terms, however, would stretch from "cheesy" to "sappy."

There are so many specialized words for this though, you can even find words that hone in on what particular emotion the movie is milking--sad, happy, heartwarming, etc.

Answer (score 5):

I would also compare **cloying**, from **cloy** (v):

> To cause distaste or disgust by supplying with too much of something originally pleasant, especially something rich or sweet; surfeit. [[source: AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=cloying)]

For example, used in this [New York Times review  of *The Hunchback of Notre Dame* (1996)](http://www.nytimes.com/movie/review?res=9901E3DE1539F932A15755C0A960958260):

> Or so it often seems during "The Hunchback of Notre Dame," the latest and most uncertain of Disney's animated efforts, with its manic mood swings and cloying, none-too-cuddly hero.

Answer (score 5):

**Contrived**

Definition:

> Adjective
>   1. obviously planned or forced; artificial; strained:

Use in a sentence:

> A contrived story.

Source: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/contrived

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest,

***mushy***

> *informal* Excessively sentimental: *a mushy film* [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mushy)

***gooey***

> Mawkishly sentimental [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gooey)

Comment: Why not just sentimental then?

Comment: @Mitch Because "sentimental" doesn't necessarily imply "sappy." A movie can be sentimental without being mawkishly sentimental.

Answer (score 0):

Another word commonly used in reviews is **[Camp](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/camp#h3)** which according to M-W means:

> "style or mode of personal or creative expression that is absurdly
>   exaggerated and often fuses elements of high and popular culture"

In this case however the emotion being invoked is frequently humor or nostalgia through over the top references to other eras, styles, cliches, etc.  Many movies fit this criteria, a couple examples would be Expendables 2 and Thankskilling

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean *cliche*?

**from wikipedia:**

> A cliché or cliche (/ˈkliːʃeɪ/ or /klɪˈʃeɪ/) is an expression, idea, or element of an artistic work which has become overused to the point of losing its original meaning or effect, even to the point of being trite or irritating, especially when at some earlier time it was considered meaningful or novel.

Comment: Cliche could be nearly anything, this is too vague.